# Spring Boot: One auto-configuration for prod and another one for unit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, mocking

I'm working on a library which has two maven modules: `core` and `test`. Both of the modules come with an auto-configuration class (defined in `spring.factories`).

`test` actually is dependent on `core` (it uses its interfaces and supply mock classes).

Now, as a user of the library I'd like to:

- On production, to `@Autowire` the real implementation
- On unit-testing to `@Autowire` the mocked implementation

So I guess I need to use some `@CondiationalOn...` classes but how exactly?